# ADB Access in TWRP recovery mode - samsung A3, Linux

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, twrp, samsung-galaxy-a3

I can access my Samsung A3 (a3xelte) in "normal" mode in Linux using adb.
Today I installed the TWRP 3.2.3-0 recovery mode and entered it. According to [this DroidWiki article](https://www.droidwiki.org/wiki/TeamWin_Recovery_Project#ADB_im_Recovery)(the article is in German), I should be able to use adb commands in this mode as well. However, "adb devices" shows me nothing. Any ideas or is the information wrong for this phone?

Reason I am asking: After resetting the phone to factory settings, some valuable Memo-Notes seem to be deleted. I would like to copy an image of the partition to my computer (as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49287932/2135504) from StackOverflow), and then use testdisk to potentially still find the relevant deleted file. The phone is not rooted which seems to make things a lot more complicated...

Comment: Sounds like you don't have the correct drivers installed... The ones used for the device when the OS is running may not be the same as when in TWRP, which are the generic Android ADB drivers. The link you gave in your question even mentions this. Unless you use Linux, then you don't need any drivers.

Comment: I am using linux (even in topic). So shall I install different drivers?

Comment: No, Linux doesn't use "drivers" fir this, the modules are built in the kernel. I would contact your maintainer (likely via the XDA forums official post for TWRP for this device) and determine the issue. They may have had to implement it differently due to device constraints.